# how to send data from Android activity to Fragment

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment

[image]

I want to send data from LoginActivity to FragmentIndividual.
I've been thinking about it for two days, but I haven't solved it.
I don't know why NullPointer happens.
I'd really appreciate it if you could attach the code together.

---

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    // Initialize Firebase Auth
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    final FragmentTransaction t = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    final FragmentIndividual fragmentIndividual = new FragmentIndividual();
    login_btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.signIn);
    e1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.idText);
    login_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Bundle b2 = new Bundle();
            b2.putString("email", e1.getText().toString());
            fragmentIndividual.setArguments(b2);
            t.add(R.id.fram1234, fragmentIndividual);
            t.commit();
        }
    });

    TextView signup = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.signUp);
    signup.setOnClickListener(new TextView.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent signupIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SignupActivity.class);
            startActivity(signupIntent);
        }
    });

    findViewById(R.id.signIn).setOnClickListener(onClickLisener);
    findViewById(R.id.pwResetBtn).setOnClickListener(onClickLisener);
}
```

---

```
public class FragmentIndividual extends Fragment {
TextView t1;

public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_individual, container, false);
    t1 = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.emailTv);
    Bundle b3 = getArguments();
    String email = b3.getString("email");
    t1.setText(email);

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_individual, container, false);
}
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Send data from activity to fragment in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12739909/send-data-from-activity-to-fragment-in-android)

Comment: You should return v in onCreateView, which was already inflated, instead of inflating again.

Comment: You could try moving this line `final FragmentTransaction t = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();` into the `onClick()` method for the login button.

Comment: Please don't post images of errors, post the errors as text.  Also, are you sure this is the only place you create this Fragment?

Answer (score 0):

create method constructor in fragment example below :

```
public class ExampleFragment extends Fragment 
{
String  currency;
List<model> list ;
public ExampleFragment(List<model> list , String currency) {
    this.list = list;
    this.currency=currency;
}
}
```

Comment: This is terrible advice.  This will only cause more crashes later, because `Fragment`s must have no-argument constructors.